# How to generate unique token for Client Id & Client Secret for OAuth 2 in PHP?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an OAuth Server in PHP. Currently using PHP Library `http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/` for it. Till now everything has been clear. Just want to know how to create the unique token for Client Id & Client Secret in PHP.

Now, I'm using the following piece of code for creating Client Id & Client Secret token.

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
```

But, a little bit confuses. whether, Is it a right way to do this thing or not?  I also searched for any library to do this. But, didn't get one.

Comment: Any thought on this ? -.-

Answer (score 4):

For PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7

Use [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

```
$client_secret = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
```

There is also an article about OAuth 2.0 Client SecretID [The Client ID and Secret](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/)

For PHP 7
Use random_bytes

```
$client_secret = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
```